# Prove that $\alpha(x)=(0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$ is not injective

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $S$ be a vector space of real sequences and, for $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots)$ and define $\alpha(x)=(0,x_1,x_2,\dots)$.

Now the first part of the question asks you to show that $\alpha$ is a linear map, which is fine. I'm just wondering how to show that it's not injective, I was trying to think of a simple counter example but I can't seem to find one. I then tried to prove it by trying to find a contraction using the definition of injectivity.
$$ \forall x,y\in S \;\;\alpha(x)=\alpha(y) \implies x=y $$
So using the property of it being a linear map:
$$ \alpha(x)-\alpha(y)=\alpha(x-y)=0_S \rightarrow (0,x_1-y_1,x_2-y_2,\dots)=(0,0,0,\dots) $$
then comparing elements $ x_j=y_j$ which would then surely imply that $x=y$. But clearly that's not the case since it asks me to prove that it isn't injective. Any pointers as to how to approach this problem would be great!

Comment: If $a(x)=a(y)$ then $x=y$, so $a$ **is** injective. It is not surjective. Are you sure you have the correct definition for $a$? (It might be $(0,x_2,...)$ instead?)

Comment: @copper.hat yeah that's definitely the definition of $\alpha(x)$. Though the question also defines $\beta(x)=(x_2,x_3,\dots)$ and then the next part of the question asks you to show that $\beta$ is *not* surjective.

Comment: $\beta$ **is** surjective.

Comment: Is it possible they meant the image to be $(0,x_2,x_3,\dots)$? This would be neither injective nor surjective.

Comment: @copper.hat is $\beta(x)$ not injective? In which case maybe they are the wrong way round.

Comment: I would presume that the question has a mistake. Trust your mathematics :-).

Comment: Looks like the problem set got them backwards. because $\beta$ is surjective.

Comment: $\beta((1,0,0,..)) = \beta((2,0,0,....))$, so no, $\beta$ is not injective.

Comment: If you prove that $\alpha$ is not injective (or that $\beta$ is not surjective), you can literally prove anything after that.

Comment: @copper.hat that's what I was thinking. Yeah they must have just got the labels the wrong way round then. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Jay: You are very welcome.